# How to populate a mx:ViewStack dynamically with a dataProvider for a tabbed navigation?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

I'm very sleepy right now, so this is just an example of what I want (obviously this code is wrong):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application
xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Declarations>

        <s:ArrayCollection id="dp"> 
            <fx:Object label="Just a label" text="Bla bla bla..."/>
            <fx:Object label="Just a label" text="Bla bla bla..."/>
            <fx:Object label="Just a label" text="Bla bla bla..."/>
        </s:ArrayCollection>

    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:ButtonBar dataProvider="{tabs}" />

    <mx:ViewStack id="tabs" resizeToContent="true">

        <s:DataGroup dataProvider="{dp}">

            <s:NavigatorContent label="{data.label}">
                <s:Label text="{data.text}"/>
            </s:NavigatorContent>

        </s:DataGroup>

    </mx:ViewStack>

</s:Application>
```

How can I do something like that? (the NavigationContent will be the itemRenderer and the ButtonBar is very important).

Comment: Maybe you need to revisit this question after some rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put a data group inside of a `ViewStack` directly... the items need to implement `INavigatiorContent`.

So, this is about the best I can come up with.  It certainly doesn't handle updates to the `ArrayCollection` or anything more advanced than this, but it is a start.

```
<s:VGroup>
    <s:ButtonBar dataProvider="{tabs}" />

    <mx:ViewStack id="tabs" resizeToContent="true"  >
        <mx:addedToStage>
            <![CDATA[
                for(var i:int = 0; i < dp.length; i++) {
                    var label:Label = new Label();
                    label.text = dp.getItemAt(i).text;

                    var context:NavigatorContent = new NavigatorContent();
                    context.label = dp.getItemAt(i).label;
                    context.addElement(label);

                    tabs.addChild(context);
                }
            ]]>
        </mx:addedToStage>
    </mx:ViewStack>
</s:VGroup>
```

If I were to really make this happen, I would create a new class that derives from `ViewStack` that includes a `dataProvider` property.  Internally, I would listen to changes on the collection so that it would add/remove items.  This class would also include an `itemRenderer` property so that you can define what the tabs look like.

The problem with this is that with tabs, usually, you have specific views that go along with data.  You would probably want to include an `itemRendererFunction` to do the mapping for you.

It would get kind of messy and leaky... but you could make it happen.